# CASE Condition doesn't return the value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.Nama_Merchant = 'SNOOPY SHOP' AND a.Alamat_Merchant <> 'xxx' AND a.Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI' THEN '1' 
        WHEN a.Nama_Merchant <> 'SNOOPY SHOP' AND a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx' AND a.Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI' THEN '1' 
        WHEN a.Nama_Merchant = 'SNOOPY SHOP' AND a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx' AND a.Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI' THEN '1' 
        ELSE '0' 
    END AS keterangan 
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM merchant_negative_db_Copy mndb
     WHERE (Nama_Merchant LIKE 'SNOOPY SHOP' OR Alamat_Merchant LIKE 'xxx' OR Nama_Pemilik LIKE 'HENI')
       AND flag_merchant = '0') a
```

But when I try to run the query it showing that keterangan return value 0 even though one of condition meet requirements.

The result of query

| Nama_Merchant | Alamat_Merchant | Nama_Pemilik | Keterangan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SNOOPY SHOP | xxx | GUNAWAN | 0 |
| 4G SOFA | yyy | HENI | 0 |
| SMART VONE 88 | zzz | HENI | 0 |

Sample starting data

| Nama_Merchant | Alamat_Merchant | Nama_Pemilik |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SNOOPY SHOP | xxx | GUNAWAN |
| 4G SOFA | yyy | HENI |
| SMART VONE 88 | zzz | HENI |
| SCUTO | aaa | BERLIANA |
| BNS | bbb | SUGENG |
| CCCAAS | ccc | ANDRE |

I expect SNOOPY SHOP's Keterangan value is 1

| Nama_Merchant | Alamat_Merchant | Nama_Pemilik | Keterangan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SNOOPY SHOP | xxx | GUNAWAN | 1 |

Can you point out where in my query logic is not proper?

Comment: None of your conditions are true for the data... so why do you expect a 1? All of them require that `Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI'` which is not the case for you "SNOOPY SHOP".

Comment: ooh I see what if I just change like this `WHEN a.Nama_Merchant = 'SNOOPY SHOP' AND a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx'  THEN '1' WHEN  a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx' AND a.Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI' THEN '1' 
WHEN a.Nama_Merchant = 'SNOOPY SHOP' AND a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx' AND a.Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI' THEN '1' 
ELSE '0' ` does that make query bad?

Comment: i deleted `nama_pemilik = 'HENI'` in first case and `a.nama_merchant ='yyy'` in second case

Comment: Only you know what logic you are aiming for and whether that accomplishes it or now.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation does not match the SQL criteria.

| Nama_Merchant | Alamat_Merchant | Nama_Pemilik | Keterangan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SNOOPY SHOP | xxx | GUNAWAN | 1 |

The rules state that `Keterangan` is 1 (for *SNOOPY SHOP*) only when either of the following is true:

1. `Nama_Merchant`= SNOOPY SHOP
   `Alamat_Merchant` **NOT** xxx
   `Nama_Pemilik`= HENI
2. `Nama_Merchant`= SNOOPY SHOP
   `Alamat_Merchant` **=** xxx
   `Nama_Pemilik`= HENI

These two conditions end up cancelling out the `Alamat_Merchant` criteria altogether, this is probably not what you intended.

Given the current state of *SNOOPY SHOP* neither of these rules match because `Nama_Pemilik` is not *HENI*:

| Nama_Merchant | Alamat_Merchant | Nama_Pemilik |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SNOOPY SHOP | xxx | GUNAWAN |

---

#### UPDATE:

From the comments, you have suggested changing the criteria to this:

```
CASE
    WHEN a.Nama_Merchant = 'SNOOPY SHOP' AND a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx'  THEN '1' 
    WHEN a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx' AND a.Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI' THEN '1'  
    WHEN a.Nama_Merchant = 'SNOOPY SHOP' AND a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx' AND a.Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI' THEN '1'  
    ELSE '0'
END
```

But again, the 3rd expression will never be executed.

SQL will evaluate `CASE` expressions from left to right, and will exit the switch at the first *truthy* statement.

Because the first rule is true, the others do not get checked, notice that rule 3 starts off the same as rule 1, meaning data that matches rule 1 will never get checked against rule 3 (that was going to assign the same number anyway).

No other record is a can match RULE 1 or 3 because no other record has the `Nama_Merchant` as *SNOOPY SHOP*.

No Other record can match RULE 2 because on the *SNOOPY SHOP* record has an `Alamat_Merchant` = *xxx*

It can sometimes help to visualise this as 3 separate `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.Nama_Merchant = 'SNOOPY SHOP' AND a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx' THEN '1'
    END AS Rule1,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx' AND a.Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI' THEN '1'
    END AS Rule2,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.Nama_Merchant = 'SNOOPY SHOP' AND a.Alamat_Merchant = 'xxx' AND a.Nama_Pemilik = 'HENI' THEN '1'  
    END AS Rule3
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM merchant_negative_db_Copy mndb
     WHERE (Nama_Merchant LIKE 'SNOOPY SHOP' OR Alamat_Merchant LIKE 'xxx' OR Nama_Pemilik LIKE 'HENI')
       AND flag_merchant = '0') a
```

| Nama_Merchant | Alamat_Merchant | Nama_Pemilik | Rule1 | Rule2 | Rule3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SNOOPY SHOP | xxx | GUNAWAN | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4G SOFA | yyy | HENI | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| SMART VONE 88 | zzz | HENI | 0 | 0 | 0 |